# Pandas plotting dataframe specific column count as bar

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

If I have a data frame as below

```
column1                column2
key1Str         valueAsString1
key2Str         valueasString2
key2Str         valueasString1
key1Str         valueasString2
key3Str         valueasString1
key1Str         valueasString2
```

I wanted to plot this as bar graph where x-axis is each key and each value and y should be count of each value in data frame. I'm fairly new to python and tried to do as follows.

plot summary as (key1 - value1Count, value2Count, key2- value1Count, value2Count....)

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
for key in df['column1'].unique():
    data_=df[df['column1']==key]
    data_['column2'].values_count().plot(kind='bar', ax=ax)
plt.show()
```

it just shows one graph at the end, what's the better way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

IIUC:

```
import seaborn as sns

sns.barplot(x='column1', y='cnt', hue='column2',
            data=df.groupby(df.columns.tolist()).size().to_frame('cnt').reset_index())
```

[image]

Comment: Thankx MaxU, this works per key count, I wanted to have separate bars per value as well, since the values are also shared across all keys and very limited

Comment: @SKR, do you mean something like: `df.groupby(['column1','column2']).size().plot.bar()`?

Comment: Thanks, yes group by both columns worked as expected, but through seaborn is much cleaner.

Comment: @SKR, glad I could help :-)